Finding Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors for large symbolic systems
I want to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a Jacobian symbolically for a solid dynamics system.
The problem is that the Jacobian is large, with 12x12 elements, and some of the elements have multiple terms.
The Jacobian is given by:
$$\left.\mathcal{A}_N=\left(\begin{array}{cc}-\frac{\partial(PN)}{\partial p}&-\frac{\partial(PN)}{\partial F}\\-\frac{\partial\left(\frac1{\rho_0}p\otimes N\right)}{\partial p}&-\frac{\partial\left(\frac1{\rho_0}p\otimes N\right)}{\partial F}\end{array}\right.\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0_{3\times3}&-\mathcal{C}_N\\-\frac1{\rho_0}\boldsymbol{I}_N&\mathbf{0}_{9\times9}\end{array}\right)$$
where
$$
[\mathcal{C}_{N}]_{ijJ}=\frac{\partial P_{iI}}{\partial F_{jJ}}N_{I},\quad[\boldsymbol{I}_{N}]_{iIk}=\delta_{ik}N_{I}.
$$
here $\mathbf{p}$ is the vector of linear momentum, $\mathbf{F}$ is the gradient deformation tensor, $\mathbf{P}$ is Piola-Kirshof stress tensor, $\mathbf{N}$ is a unit normal vector and,  $\mathcal{C}_N$ denotes a normal component of any constitutive material fourthorder tensor $\mathcal{C}=\partial\boldsymbol{P}/\partial\boldsymbol{F}$. For the case of nearly incompressible Neo-Hookean (NH) $\mathrm{material,the~stress~tensor~is~formulated~as}$
$$
\boldsymbol{P}(\boldsymbol{F})=\mu J^{-2/3}\left[\boldsymbol{F}-\frac{1}{3}(\boldsymbol{F}:\boldsymbol{F})\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}\right]+\kappa(J-1)J\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}
$$
the nonlinear elasticity tensor $\mathcal{C}$ can then be derived as
$$\begin{aligned}&\mathcal{C}(\boldsymbol{F})=\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{P}}{\partial\boldsymbol{F}}=-\frac{2}{3}\mu J^{-2/3}\boldsymbol{F}\otimes\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}+\frac{2}{9}\mu J^{-2/3}(\boldsymbol{F}:\boldsymbol{F})\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}\otimes\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}\\&+\mu J^{-2/3}\mathcal{I}-\frac{1}{3}\mu J^{-2/3}(\boldsymbol{F}:\boldsymbol{F})\mathcal{H}-\frac{2}{3}\mu J^{-2/3}\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}\otimes\boldsymbol{F}\\&+\kappa J(2J-1)\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}\otimes\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}+\kappa J(J-1)\boldsymbol{H}.\end{aligned}$$
Here,
$$\mathcal{H} = \partial\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}/\partial\boldsymbol{F} = -F_{iJ}^{-T}F_{jI}^{-T},\quad \partial J/\partial\boldsymbol{F} = J\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}, \quad \boldsymbol{I} = \delta_{ij}\delta_{1J}.$$
You can see how complicated the system. The main problem is with $\mathcal{C}_N$. For the linear case, the whole relation is reduced, and Mathematica/Maple/Python-Symby/Matlab can solve the eigenproblem; however, once I run the nonlinear case, it runs endlessly.
Please provide me with any resources or references for solving this problem. I feel that I am missing a trick to do it.
Any lead is highly appreciated, as this problem has stopped research.

The 12x12 block matrix  $A$ will be typeset below as a list of sub-blocks::
$$A= \{ \{ 0_{3x3}, - C_{3x9}\}, \{-D_{9x3}, 0_{9x9}\}\}$$
Any eigenvector $V$ can be written as a column vector that splits into two parts of column length 3 and 9 respectively: $V=[v_3, v_9]$
The eigen-equation $\lambda V  =  AV$  then boils down to two separate conditions:
(a) $\lambda v_3=- Cv_9  $ and
(b) $ \lambda v_9= -D v_3$
Multiply (a) by $\lambda$  and multiply (b)  on the left by $C$   to deduce that
$\lambda^2 v_3 =- C\lambda v_9= CD v_3$ . Thus you see that  $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $CD$ which is a 3x3 matrix. Note that $v_3$ is the associated eigenvector.
This smaller matrix problem might have an explicit analytic  solution for $\lambda^2$ and also perhaps  allow you to compute $v_3$.
P.S. Of course you can also by similar methods show that $\lambda^2$ must be an eigenvalue of the 9x9 matrix $DC$ and perhaps solve for $v_9$.

So, let me get this straight. First, Find the CD matrix, which is a 3x3 matrix. Then, calculate the eigenvalues of CD. Using each eigenvalue solve for $v_3$ in $\lambda^2 v_3 = CD v_3$. finally solve  $v_9$ in $- C\lambda v_9= CD v_3$. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
Also, could you please mention a reference so I can learn more? Thanks!

Yes. I suggest you first work out a concrete numerical example and confirm that it agrees with the result of other methods.

P.S. Actually note that  once you know $v_3$ and $\lambda$, you can  solve for $v_9$ easily  from the equation $\lambda v_9 = - D v_3$

Hi @mathfont , I am back with a small doubt. Solving for  $λ^2 v_3=CD v_3$ results in three eigenvalues $\lambda^2_i$ and corresponding eigenvector $v_{3i}$. Then, to get the full six eigenvalues we take $\pm\sqrt{\lambda_i}$. my question is regarding the full set of eigen vectors, what is the corresponding eigenvector in this case?
